# How to have an emacs function called when display size changes?

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to define an emacs function that will be called when the display size changes, currently I'm not finding any hooks that I can use for this.

I an NOT trying to notice when the emacs window changes size.

My use case is that I have emacs open on my laptop, then I close it and bring it to work and plug it into a bigger monitor and turn it on via the keyboard. After logging in my windows are all in the top left corner.

I want emacs to notice the screen size change and call my function allow me to reposition the window *and* change the font size.

yes, I know about [stay](http://cordlessdog.com/stay/) but I also want to change the font size.

I'm running emacs 24.3.1 from emacsformacosx.com under OSX Mavericks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, Emacs currently does not catch such screen-size-change events, and even if it does internally, it doesn't expose this in any way to ELisp.  So your two best bets might be:

- Use a timer that checks the screen size to detect change.
- Ask for the feature via `M-x report-emacs-bug`.